How to make scrollable game that follows the main character if we use keys or scroll if we use the wheel with Phaser3?
It is my first time using Phaser3 and I am trying to create a game to display in a website. My plan was to make a vertical map that you can navigate either with the keys and scrolling. The thing is that I do not find any examples online, since if the camera follows the character, I do not manage to make the scroll work, and the other way around. Here is a snipet of my code in case it helps
//Creo la configuracion del juego
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: 2000,
    scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.NONE,
        parent: 'game',
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH
    },
    backgroundColor: '#000000', //fondo
    parent: 'game', //Donde se va a renderizar
    physics:{
        default: 'arcade', // arcade, impact o matery
        arcade: {
            gravity: {y: 300},
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload, //cargamos imagenes, recursos etc
        create: create, //usamos esas imagenes, recursos
        update: update //se actualiza contantemente
    }
}

//Inicializo el juego con la configuracion
new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload(){ //1
    this.load.image(
        'dessert-background',
        'assets/background/dessert-bg.jpg'
    );

    //Sprite character
    this.load.spritesheet(
        'hero', //id, solo puede haber uno con ese id
        'assets/entities/hero_sprite.png',
        {frameWidth:64, frameHeight: 64} 
    ); 
}

function create(){ //2

    let bg = this.add.image(0, 0, 'dessert-background')
        .setOrigin(0, 0);

    bg.displayWidth = this.sys.game.config.width;
    bg.displayHeight = this.sys.game.config.height;
    bg.alpha = 0.3; //transparencia

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        bg.displayWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth - scrollbarWidth
    });

    this.hero = this.physics.add.sprite(50,100,'hero')
        .setOrigin(0,1)
        .setCollideWorldBounds(true)
        .setGravityY(300);

    this.physics.world.setBounds(0,0,config.width, 2000);
    this.cameras.main.setBounds(0,0,config.width, 2000);
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.hero, true, 0.1, 0.1); // Suavizado de seguimiento

    createAnimations(this);

    this.keys = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}


Sound intersting but how would you want to control the camera, with the player and scrolling? You would somehow would have to switch between both modes, or so. or how would you want to control this functions?

@winner_joiner yes! finally I did that switching between the camera and the keys:
`this.input.keyboard.on('keydown', () => {
this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.piper, true, 0.1, 0.1);
});
// Evento de scroll para detener el seguimiento de la cámara y mover scroll
this.input.on('wheel', function(pointer){
    this.cameras.main.stopFollow();

}`

Thank you for your feedback, I'm glad to here that it works for you.

If you only want to move the camera with the scroll-wheel, you can use the the input-event wheel (link to the documentation).
And just move the camera, by setting the scrollY property.
Short demo:


const config = {
    width: 500,
    height: 180,
    scene: {
        create
    }
}

function create(){
    let label = this.add.text(10, 10, 'Demo Scroll to move the camera up or down')
      .setOrigin(0);
      
    this.add.line( 0, 1300, 0, 0, 500, -2600, 0xffff00 )
      .setOrigin(0);
      
    this.input.on('wheel', function(pointer){
        if(pointer.deltaY > 0){
          this.cameras.main.scrollY += 10;
        } else if(pointer.deltaY < 0){
          this.cameras.main.scrollY -= 10;
        }
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>



